# PHP Desde Web & Comando de Linea

Tags: php

ya antes habia hecho una publicación acerca de este problema.

Ahora lo dejare mas detallado.

Tengo un script descargado de github llamado **InstagramLive-PHP** [Enlace](https://github.com/JRoy/InstagramLive-PHP)

Cuestión que solo se permite CLI es decir solo comando de linea, pero estuve leyendo que se puede ejecutar mediante web.

Archivo: goLive.php

```php
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli") {
    die("This script may not be run on a website!");
}
```

Bueno principalmente que hace este dichoso Script? Pues al ejecutar goLive.php por linea de comando crea un acceso a un directo que se crea por este archivo. Es decir en la linea de comando te tiraria el token y el rmtps.

Una vez con esos datos podes ingresar al OBS colocando esos datos y ya podrias hacer el directo desde tu ordenador.

A lo que va mi problema, es que use el el siguiente codigo:

Archivo prueba.php

```php
<?php
$output = shell_exec("php goLive.php --web");
echo "$output";
?>
```

Se queda cargando, pero si se ejecuta y crea un directo, pero no me arroja ningun resultado del token o datos para poner en el OBS.

En la web arroja el siguiente texto:

> Loading InstagramLive-PHP v2.0-stable (66)...

Cuando cierro el proceso php.exe desde el administrador de tareas sale todo el texto

> Login: Starting Instagram logon, please wait... Login: Successfully logged in as bestOftwo! 
>   Livestream: Creating livestream... 
>   Livestream: Created livestream! OBS Integration: OBS not detected, disabling! Please make a ticket on GitHub if you have OBS installed. ================================ Stream URL ================================ rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/ ================================ Stream URL ================================ ======================== Current Stream Key ======================== 18077155756095783?s_efg=eyJxZV9ncm91cHMiOnsiaWdfbGl2ZV9lbmFibGVfcG9wX3ByaW1pbmciOnsiZW5hYmxlZCI6InRydWUifSwiaWdfbG93X2xhdGVuY3lfcHJvZHVjdGlvbl91bml2ZXJzZSI6eyJlbmFibGVkIjoidHJ1ZSJ9fX0%3D&s_sw=0&s_vt=ig&a=AbwQAolxKd1GacfG ======================== Current Stream Key ======================== Windows: Your stream key has been pre-copied to your clipboard. Please start streaming to the url and key above! Once you are live, please press enter! Livestream: Starting livestream... Livestream: Started livestream! Command Line: Windows/macOS Detected! A new console will open for command input and this will display command and livestream output.

Cualquier ayuda me vendria bien, mas que nada quiero saber si se puede ejecutar o hay alguna forma de ejecutar los CLI en web, acepto que ocasionaria errores y demas.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: *`Your stream key has been pre-copied to your clipboard`* Parece que copia algo en el portapapeles. ¿Has intentado el comando Pegar  luego de esta llamada para ver si es así?

Comment: Hola A. Cedrano, si vi que copia algo en portapepeles y es la key del stream, pero lo que quiero y necesito es que se muestre de forma automatica todo eso en una ventana emergente o popup, pero en si solo queda en blanco. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Entonces supongo que tendrás que modificar el script para que, en vez de copiar los datos en el portapales, los muestre en pantalla.

Comment: Claro, les puse un return, pero a la hora de querer mostrar en la pantalla no lo hace, es mas queda como en loop la pagina, ahora le echare un ojo con mas tiempo a ver que puede ser, desde ya gracias por tu ayuda.